# Complex Timesheet Form

Tags: forms

Hopefully I'm posting this in the correct place...

I need to create a complex timesheet that will be on a WordPress page. The example image attached shows exactly what I need to create (it's the current timesheet that is used offline).

It needs to be mobile-friendly as well.

And then it would submit, hopefully, to a PDF or similar which would be formatted visually the same as the form, so it's easy for the HR department to read and understand.

I've looked at various wordpress form plugins and addons and haven't found anything that appears to easily do something this complex.

Suggestions?

[image: Current timesheet]

Comment: Personally I'd code it in raw php, instead of trying to dovetail it with WordPress, but... Timesheet could be a post_type and all of the fields could be built using ACF or native WordPress post-meta. As for exporting to a pdf... Normally I render an html-page and then pass it through wkhtmltopdf. Or you could do another graphic format using ImageMagick or image.intervention. Though if the comment below does the trick, then go with it, I've used Gravity Forms extensively but didn't know they've added an export to pdf function.

Comment: I'd hire a developer if I were in your place.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the gravity forms plugin. It will allow you to have a pdf emailed or stored in the database.

Comment: Normally answers should be a bit longer and shorter responses reserved for comments, but it's sounds advice and you can't comment until 50 rep. Consider this upvoted, nice work!